# Randomized Polynomial Hierarchy?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, randomized-algorithms, randomness

I wonder, what would happen, if in the definition of $PH$ (Polynomial Hierarchy, see, e.g., [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_hierarchy)), the role of $NP$ would be replaced by $RP$?

It seems, we could still build a hierarchy, the same way as $PH$ is built, just using $RP$ everywhere instead of $NP$, and $coRP$ instead of $coNP$. Let us call it Randomized Polynomial Hierarchy ($RPH$).

My first guess is that $RPH\subseteq BPP$, or maybe $RPH=BPP$. It is based on the known  fact that $NP=RP$ implies $PH=BPP$. Nevertheless, if $P\neq RP$, then $RPH$ could still be a proper, infinite hierarchy within $BPP$.

Of course, the edge of the issue is blunted by the fact that $P=RP$ is conjectured (even $P=BPP$), which would flatten $RPH$ into $P$.  However, $P=RP$  is not known at this time, and it has resisted all proof attempts so far. Therefore,  $RPH$ still has at least some chance to be a proper hierarchy.

While $RPH$, admittedly, has a good chance to be "flat," could the concept still be useful for something nontrivial? Here is an example: if one can prove $RPH=BPP$, then it would yield that $P=RP$ implies $P=BPP$, which, I think,  would be an interesting result.

Is anything known about this?

Comment: What does it mean exactly to have RP as an oracle, e.g. $P^{RP}$?

Comment: @usul : $\:$ http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/26332/12859 $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 8):

Clearly, $\mathrm{RPH}\subseteq\mathrm{BPP}$. On the other hand, $\mathrm{BPP}=\mathrm{ZPP^{promiseRP}}$ ([Buhrman&Fortnow](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-49116-3_9), [pdf](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~fortnow/papers/rpvsbpp.pdf)), so the only way the hierarchy didn’t collapse to (at most) the second level and didn’t exhaust $\mathrm{BPP}$ would be for the  unlikely reason that $\mathrm{RP}$ oracles were significantly weaker than $\mathrm{promiseRP}$ oracles.